# $pull only one item from array of objects in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

When running Data.updateOne() and passing $pull, all the objects that match are removed, but I am only looking to remove one object from the array.

```
 await Data.updateOne({'UserID': user.id}, { $pull: { 'Items': { 'ItemName': result.ItemName}}})
```

I expected to only remove a single item based on matching ItemName objects from the Items array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that `Items` array is empty after this update? Do you only want to delete the first element from the `Items` array and not all elements that match the `'ItemName': result.ItemName` query? Please post your schema.